# Geolocation, Geocoding in C++

Tags: c++, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am working on a project or application built in Windows using C++. I would like to seek help on any idea or approach or existing libraries that implements geolocation/geocoding, since I want to limit may C++ Windows application to run on certain region or country only.
Any suggestions, comments will be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to prevent an application from running locally in certain regions. A user can always disconnect from the internet and then you'll have no idea where they're located.

What you could do is to have some of your app logic run in a server, then make requests to your server from the local C++ app. Then you can geolocate based on the IP address of the request, often a [standard feature](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers#app_engine-specific_headers) in cloud platforms.

If you do want to explore getting someone's location, you can look at Apple's [Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation) or Microsoft's [Geolocation namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Geolocation).

Comment: thanks for the info. Actually I already have Geolocation namespace query in Windows and it already outputs coordinates. My problem now is how to convert these coordinates to region or country names so that we can limit access of the application. This application is a standalone app. Any advice will be a great help.